# Flutter sizing elements in Column

Tags: list, flutter, dart, height

I would like to achieve in Flutter something like this in XAML:

```
<RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</RowDefinition>
```

I'm struggling with building a fraction in Flutter.

I would like my Column to render two independent containers: nominator and denominator.
And I would like them to be the same exact size. I mean when the nominator has another fraction in it, the denominator should be the same height.

Is it possible to have a Column with two elements of each size depending on the highest one?

I've been trying to use IntrinisicHeight but it doesn't work when the height isn't provided.

But XAML could render it because it would automatically be calculated and set 1:1 ratio for both elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Expanded` widget to do that:

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

The flex argument is `1` by default so you don't even need that. more about the expanded widget:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: But it doesn't work because the parents of the column don't have fixed height.